# PHP cookie time setup

Tags: php

I really do not understand the difference between time()-3600 and time()+3600 set in the cookie of PHP.

I have tried both the code time()-3600 and time()+3600 in the cookie, where I found that time()-3600 delete the cookie before it is saved. So, if the time()-3600 can delete the cookie before it is saved, can we keep any integer after the (-) to delete the cookie before it is saved?

Comment: `time()-3600` is `this cookie expired an hour ago`, `time()+3600` is `this cookie will be valid for another hour`; not sure I understand your question

Comment: Thank you for the answer, you got me well but I did not understand time() -3600. If any user accesses the page, will the cookie be expired at the time he or she had access the page or will it take some time to be expired? If the cookie expires at the same time then, instead of setting the time for 1hr, can we set it for 20 seconds? eg: time() - 20 instead of time()-3600 to expire the cookie.

Comment: yes, doesn't matter. just keep in mind that's a time for the browser's clock to respect. `server_current_time - 20` may be different from `client_current_time - 20`. I usually just set `1` instead of say  `time()-3600` when the intention is to clear the cookie.

Comment: Oh! I got it, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can place any integer after `time()-` to delete a cookie,
example

```
setcookie('test', 'SO test cookie' , time()-1);
```

That basically creates a cookie to exist only in the pass, hence deleting it.

That works in two ways,

- If You delete a cookie when it was never created it would not be created, however
- If you delete it after it was properly created say

```
    setcookie('test', 'SO test cookie' , time() + 3600); 
    // creates cookie (test)
    setcookie('test', 'SO test cookie' , time() - 3600);
    // deletes cookie (test)
```

it creates the cookie and deletes it at that same instant.

Meanwhile creating a cookie requires that you `setcookie()` and specify the time you want it to last using the `time()` method

```
setcookie('test', 'SO test cookie' , time() + 3600);
```

sets the cookie for the next one hour! and you could run calculations withing

```
setcookie('test', 'SO test cookie' , time()+ 3600 * 24); //
```

saves the cookie for `(1 hour * 24 )` hence it expires after 24 hours

Visit the [official setcookie() documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) to learn more about cookies in php

Comment: Then, what's the point of setting the cookie time to time() -3600?

Comment: Supposing my app uses cookies to login and logout users, i would use `setcookie('user', 'userinfo' , time() + 3600); ` to log in the user when they fill the login form with correct information.  and I'll use `setcookie('user', userinfo' , time() - 3600); ` to explicitly logout the user when they click the logout button

Comment: **FYI : ** However @PrajunMagar that is definitely not a good practice, that was just an example, Storing sensitive informations for security reasons i'll use [sessions](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp).


Kindly note when to user [cookies and when to use sessions](https://www.quora.com/When-should-I-use-cookies-and-when-should-I-use-sessions)